# react put some props after import class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem on my react website. 
I have a class which I export

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const CustomMapping = [
      ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'],
      ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', '@'],
      ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', '.com']
    ];

    return (
      <KeyboardedInput
        enabled
        type={this.props.type}
        value={this.props.value}
        name={this.props.name}
        defaultKeyboard={CustomMapping}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default Input;
```

and I import it in an other files and I don't know how I can add some props to complete it.

please help me ! :) 
have a good day or night ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to add some extra props to you Input?
Or do you just want to pass the expected props?

```
 class Input extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const CustomMapping = [
      ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p'],
      ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', '@'],
      ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', '.com']
    ];

    const { type, value, name, ...extraProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <KeyboardedInput
        enabled
        type={type}
        value={value}
        name={.$name}
        defaultKeyboard={CustomMapping}
        {...extraProps}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default Input;
```

In the components where you import the Input, just add them as regular props:

```
 class Whatever extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <Input
        type={'input'}
        value={'abc'} 
        name={'email'}
        color={'green'}
      />
    );
  }
}
export default Whatever;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the other file call it as

```
<Input type="input" value="abc" name="email" />
```

Also, add a constructor to input file

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
}
```